# Nginx Subdirectory Drupal + other app

Tags: php, nginx, drupal

I have a drupal app and 2 other app written in php, i want use a rewrite uri for drupal and place drupal in virtual root / and the other by their names ... and use the server cache for the img of each app.

ex :

- xxx.com or xxx.com/ --> /var/www/xxx.com/drupal/
- xxx.com/app1 or xxx.com/app1/ ----> /var/www/xxx.com/app1/
- xxx.com/app2 or xxx.com/app2/ ----> /var/www/xxx.com/app2/

I have tested : alias, root in each location, conditional $request_uri, separate config ...
and always one error : img path, php path, 404 for one of all app or drupal

so I'm really lost ...

here a test (maybe some good things) :

```
    # enforce www
if ($host !~* ^(www)) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://www.$host/$1 permanent;
}

location / {
    root   /var/www/gplaza.cl/Drupal;
    index  index.php index.html;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite  ^(.*)$  /index.php?q=$1  last;
        break;
    }

    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite  ^(.*)$  /index.php?q=$1  last;
        break;
    }
}

location /app1/ {
    alias /var/www/gplaza.cl/app1/;   
    index index.php;
}

location /app2/ {
    alias /var/www/gplaza.cl/app2/;   
    index index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/xxx.com$fastcgi_script_name;
}

location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$ {

    set $static_content /var/www/xxx.com/Drupal;

    if ($request_uri ~ ^/app1) {
        set $static_content /var/www/xxx.com/app1;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/app2) {
        set $static_content /var/www/gplaza.cl/app2;
    }

    expires     30d;
    access_log  off;
    root $static_content;
}
thank a lot if anybody can help me :)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location directives are checked in a predefined order (http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location). In your case, the regular expression for PHP files is anc cache management are consideres first, then the / location and (if / should not match) the /app1/ and /app2/ directives. As root will always match, /app1/ is never checked.

The solution is simpley: Put the /app1/ and /app2/ before the /-location directive and reload the nginx configuration.

BurninLeo

Comment: thx some much !!!!